# MemoryMappedFile has always the same size

Tags: c#, windows, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have to create a MemoryMappedFile in a C# process for some interprocess communication purposes. However, no matter what `SIZE` I pass to the `CreateNew()` method, the [Process Explorer Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) shows a size of `0x00001000` which I assume is `4096 bytes`.

What could be the reason for that?

Please find a minimal working example blow:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Threading;

namespace shared_memory_cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long SIZE = 50;
            MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmemory", SIZE);
            bool mutexCreated;
            Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);

            mutex.WaitOne();
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                writer.Write("hello there");
            }
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            Console.WriteLine("read memory now:");

            // block to look at properties in Process Explorer
            var block = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: memory mapping works at page granularity, which is most of the time 4096bytes. if you pass 50 it will be ceiling(50) = 4096.

Comment: In addition to @citykid the size is the max size in bytes , it does not necessarily mean that the actual size will reach the amount given.

Comment: Thanks alot, that explains my problem.